# How to use linq command to select this data

Tags: mysql, linq, visual-studio, select, join

I have a table named `attraction` and it has an `id` column which is a composite key with `type` of the table `price`.

> Attraction: id, name, city
>
> price: id, type, price

How can I select the data like this in one row by `linQ` in Visual Studio:

```
id, name, city, type1_price, type2_price
```

Comment: You are saying composite key formed from two columns lying in separate tables. How come? Or you are saying that `id` column in `attraction` table refers to `type` column in `price` table.

Answer (score 0):

```
You want to access anonymous type to some kind of object and to acheive this you can try like 
declare array of 
var data= new[] { new 
            { 
                Id= 0,
                Name = "",
                City = "",
                Price1 = 0,
                Price2 = 0,
            } }.ToList();

then you can write query like

data = (from a in attraction 
        join p in price on a.Id equals p.Id
        select new
        {
                Id= a.Id,
                Name = a.Name,
                City = a.City,
                Price1 = a.Price,
                Price2 = p.Price,
        }).ToList(); 

Try above
```